# Effect of pH on life? Use buffer or HCl? How about lactic acid?

Tags: ecoli, ph

I'm trying to find the effect of pH on living things like E. coli and such. At first I thought of using a buffer solution which maintains its level of pH, but it's possible that the inactive ions of each buffer have their own effect on living things that I can't account for. On the other hand, I could use hydrochloric acid and sodium hydroxide at different concentrations by diluting it. This will be a little bit more effort (I'll be diluting the acid and base myself), but much cheaper than the buffers, and I'll know that the only other ions present beside H+ and OH- are just Na+ and Cl-, the ingredients of table salt. According to [this](http://aem.asm.org/content/58/8/2513.full.pdf) paper, the effect of pH on the population also depended on the acid (HCl vs lactic acid).

I would like a second opinion on this:
**If I'm investigating the effect of pH on growth of living things, do I use specially made buffers or just properly diluted HCl and NaOH?**

Comment: What makes you think that Na+ and Cl- can be ignored? Just because they're what makes up table salt does not mean they are harmless. I am not saying they _can't_ be ignored for the purposes of this experiment either, just pointing out that you may be jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @terdon  Not saying they are to be ignored, but if anything, these are controls. I KNOW that they're there. OTOH, I have no idea what went into those buffers.

Answer (score 1):

That is a variable that you have the pleasure defining yourself. Just know that using a buffer will introduce other atoms that could affect the "living things". Conversely, if you don't use a buffer, it is likely that the pH of your "living things" will be easily altered by the metabolism of your living things (IMHO, this is worse).

I don't know the details of your project, but recommend:

-use a buffer like.. Tris, phosphate...
-use 10 mM Tris-Cl without any extra electrolyte (aside of the HCl or NaOH that you use to modulate the pH of your buffer to different pH's that you want to test)
-e.g. Tris-Cl pH 7, 8, 9.. or Phosphate pH 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9..